# Practice documents to typeset?

Tags: typography

Aside from when I read *The TeXbook*, I have only ever used TeX for immediate problems. But, I have to familiarize myself with typography in general, for a job. I am finding the documentation in TeX Live to be helpful. But, are you aware of anywhere to find exercise documents?

I mean, example layouts which you would attempt to duplicate using TeX or anything else.

Using the package documentation, I search through it to see something that looks like it would be a good exercise and then try to duplicate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Personally, I would take a look through http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319 for *inspiration*, but those can be *hard*.

Comment: Wow! That is certainly inspirational.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding typography as such, I would suggest you grab Bringhurst's *Elements of typographic style*, which is pretty much a reference in the field. He gives many examples of page layouts and formats, which you could try to reproduce – right, he doesn't give you LaTeX answers, but you can try on your own and ask a question here if you don't manage to get something right.

The other piece of advice would be to look at the possibilities offered by Peter Wilson's `memoir` class (including its rich documentation). You will find two related documents which are

- his [Notes on Book Design](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf)
- sample [Memoir class designs](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf)

You could practice with them and try to change some of the parameters to achieve different layouts. I know this isn't like an exercise book, but you can set yourself your own objectives (e.g. take a layout that resembles a book you have and tweak it so it becomes as close as possible to that design, or take a layout that does not resemble it at all and find out how to alter it properly).